# ARM Assembler code to find unpaired value in table

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a set of integers in a dcd table on ARM. They all appear an even number of times, but I'm trying to get the lone number that appears only once. Below is my algorithm in ARM.

```html
; I understand why it doesn't work obviously, but I just can't figure out better code

        AREA ExOdd1, CODE
  ENTRY
  
  LDR r1, =TABLE1
  MOV r2, #17
  MOV r6, r2
LOOP LDR r3, [r1], #4 
  B LOOP2
  SUBS r2, r2, #1
  BNE LOOP

LOOP2 LDR r4, [r1], #4  
  CMP r4, r3
  BNE LOOP2
  EOREQ r5, r3, r4
  CMP [r1], #33
  BNE LOOP2

STOP B STOP

TABLE1 DCD 10, 5, 10, 2, 5 ,95, 33, 95, 33, 10, 95, 33, 2, 10, 95, 2, 33

  END
```

Comment: I mean, edit your code into the question.

Comment: Why don't you take XOR of all numbers. That will return the number that appears once.

Answer (score 1):

```
        AREA ExOdd1, CODE
        ENTRY

        LDR r1, =TABLE1
        MOV r2, #17
LOOP    LDR r3, [r1], #4 
        EOR r4, r4, r3
        SUBS r2, r2, #1
        BNE LOOP

STOP    B STOP

TABLE1  DCD 10, 5, 10, 2, 5 ,95, 33, 95, 33, 10, 95, 33, 2, 10, 95, 2, 33
; the DCD directive just allocates all the
; needed memory locations for the values
; listed afterwards
; each value is stored in the next memory word.
        END
```